# IIS hosted .net core app is returning 404's for POST requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have this .net core 2.1 MVC application that I've deployed to IIS.

Every GET request I do works fine.
The application has some javascript for doing POST requests and this fails with a 404. While all is fine on my development setup in VS Code running kestrel.

I've followed this guide for deploying: [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) on my Windows Server 2016 machine.

Checked the `web.config` and that looks exactly like the docs. I'm a bit clueless where to look next since it's working in kestrel. Rebooting the machine also does not help.

Must be some IIS configuration issue I guess..

**EDIT**

The application has only one POST controller method, and the app is basically a copy of this controller: [githut upload example](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/sample/FileUploadSample/Controllers/StreamingController.cs)

Comment: Is the POST failing or the OPTIONS failing?

Comment: The POST request

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a CORS issue then.

Comment: No, it is all on the same site/host.

Comment: So do you have multiple post requests and all are failing or just a specific one? Can you please share JavaScript code for generating post request? It may be wrong url issue

Comment: @Flores is your website hosted as root level website or as a sub application under default or any other website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found out what the problem is.

Turns out the request size is the problem, it is too big for the defaults.
This explains why it works fine on kestrel.

The thing that odd is the fact that IIS returns a 404. According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/) it should return a subcode with the 404. I checked this triple times, but in my situation it surely does not. This mislead me a great deal.